# My android studio does not generate com,android.support dependency automatically. How can I solve this problem?

Tags: android, build.gradle, svm

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

}

Comment: can you please elaborate your error

Comment: Ok so whats the question?

Comment: how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android support libraries are now replaced by androidX. I recommend you use this new approach if you are starting a new project or [migrate](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) if you are on a previous project as support libraries are now **deprecated** and no longer maintained. [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx)